# StartActivity not working inside onPause in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile

I always want to show password activity when my Android app is on pause.

For example, when the user goes to home screen or switches app using Recents screen, password activity should appear right away to hide contents and protect to resume app. However, `startActivity` is not working as expected inside `onPause` method.

```kotlin
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

It actually executes `startActivity` when the App goes `onPause`. However, the `onCreate` of `MainActivity2` is not being called right away, but called when the app resumes. It was same inside `onStop` by the way.

Any solution or idea for this?

---

### Edit 1

AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Droid"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity2"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Droid">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()

        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

MainActivity2.kt

```kotlin
class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)
    }
}
```

These are the example code that I've tried, but still doesn't work. The process I've tried is like this. I wish that the `onCreate` of MainActivity2 is called right after the Home key is pressed.

Launch app → Home key → Recents screen (Doesn't show MainActivity2) → Resume app (onCreate of MainActivity2 is called)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In conclusion, this situation is not allowed in recent Android APIs. [This document](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts#exceptions) guides us about it. It says like this.

> Note: When such an app attempts to start a new activity, the system places that activity on top of the app's existing task but doesn't navigate away from the currently-visible task. When the user later returns to the app's task, the system starts the new activity instead of the activity that had previously been on top of the app's task.

Answer (score 0):

Startin activty in onPause() is not recommended but even then if you want to start it, then use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK while starting. This tells system to start new activity in new instance so that when current activity gets is killed by system, the new activity has time to start since its in another instance.
Here is the code :

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This should help you.

Comment: This code is still not working. `onCreate` of SecondActivity is still called when resuming the app, not right after pausing the app 

Comment: Check if you can make SecondActivity as Launcher activity. If you have 2 launchers then make original one as default using <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>. This should start SecondActivity immediately. Also I tested in my app, it does not let app go in pause state, it immediately starts my launcher activity.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! However, it still doesn't work. You can have a look at edited post to see my example code.